# How can I integrate strapi as CMS in my website, meaning i don't want all the backend built with strapi,

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-management-system, strapi

I just want the blog part built with strapi the rest is going to be an express backend.
If so how can I implement it ?

Comment: Your question is unfortunately not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO. I'd suggest that you do research on if it is possible to do what you seek, or find a professional which can help you implement int.

Answer (score 0):

Strapi uses node js(koa) and is customizable. you can you express with strapi.
I would recommend you to use strapi and do rest customization in strapi using koa or express(will be a bit complicated).
otherwise you will have to host strapi and use it in your app with the help of rest api.
if you are using one of the following db PostgreSQL, MongoDB, SQLite, MySQL and MariaDB. then for your app as well as strapi you can simply have one database.